# Reason for DOMElement::getAttribute() returning an empty string when there is no such attribute

Tags: php, dom

In the [php docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) it says:

> **Return Values**
>
> The value of the attribute, or an empty string if no attribute with the given name is found.

Does anybody know the reason for returning an empty string instead of just `NULL`?

Comment: If you want to know wether or not an attribute exists, use `DOMElement::hasAttribute()`.

Comment: @jmz Thx, I know about that function, I'm just curious as to why the devs made it return an empty string in that case, if it has something to do with XML in general, or if it's just an arbitrary decision they made..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the DOM specification is not platform-specific.  It was written to be implemented in a wide variety of programming languages, so it tends not to assume the existence of types such as `null`.  The W3C can assume the existence of a string type, so it's safe to use an empty string.

So the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-DOM-Level-1-19981001/level-one-core.html) reads as this:

```
DOMString                 getAttribute(in DOMString name);
```

So a string is the expected type on a cross-platform basis.  PHP's DOMDocument conforms to this.

Comment: Great answer. There's even a definition for a `getAttribute` method in the specification, which says in the "Return Value" section: `The Attr value as a string, or the empty string if that attribute does not have a specified or default value.`

Comment: @AmadeusDrZaius My understanding (nowhere documented AFAIK) is that PHP only implements DOM Level 1. Which is boneheaded, but there you are.

Comment: @lonesomeday True, my comment doesn't really add anything. I'll delete in 30...29...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters what it returns. To check the validity of the result you need to call `DOMElement::hasAttribute()` anyway.

It could be just because they want to keep it simple and have everything return strings instead of a magic value of a different type (like `null`).

Comment: Could be a valid answer, although I'd like to know (just curious) what the devs were thinking when they wrote the function like that

Comment: If you want a really really good answer I'd put a bounty on it.